# How to call a function with a function as parameter?

Tags: javascript

As a beginner in Javascript, I am trying to call a function whose parameter is a function.But I get this error.

```
function execute(f) {
  f();
}

var m = function(x) { return x * x };
m(8)                          #=> returns 64    
execute(m(8))                 #=>  Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

I guess function `execute` is executing `m(8)` before exercising its body, therefore the call becomes `execute(64)`.  If so, how do I go about passing a function with a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass them as separate parameters and use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

For example :

```
function execute(f, args) {
   return f.apply(null, args);
}

var m = function(x) { return x * x };
m(8)                            
execute(m, [8])
```

Now, let's suppose you want to have functions taking any number of arguments, and you don't want to bother with making an array. Then it's a little more fun :

```
function execute() {
  return arguments[0].apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

var m = function(x,y) { return x * y };
console.log(m(8, 4))                  
console.log(execute(m, 8, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to partially apply 8 to m:

```
function execute(f) {
  f();
}

var m = function(x) { return x * x };

execute(m.bind(null, 8))
```